# mobile receipt printing with J2ME via Bluetooth

Tags: java-me, printing, mobile, bluetooth, point-of-sale

I need to make an app in J2ME that can be able to read a SMS and then print it on an epson tm-p60 printer(ESC/POS emulation) via bluetooth.

i looked at the epson supprt site but the only ADK/drivers they provide are for:

1.Sun Java2 SDK Standard Edition Version 1.4.2_10
2.Sun Java2 SDK Standard Edition Version 1.4.2_04
3.Sun Java SE Development Kit 6 Update 3

so i don't know how am i gonna be able to use ESC/POS commands inJ2ME.

I'm a bit clueless on how i will approach this project.. plus w/c would be better to use for this project? Netbeans or Eclipse?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

SPP (Serial Port Profile) over Bluetooth means using an RFCOMM connection to send and receive data as if it were a physical serial connection.  This is part of JSR 82, so you will be able to develop only on handsets that support this JSR.

You need to:

- Figure out how to discover bluetooth devices, and scan for SPP services on a discovered device, then connect to one of those services, using one of the many [JSR 82 tutorials](http://www.jsr82.com) out there.
- Then send ESC/POS protocol data over that connection -- I assume you have the protocol specification available?  Google turned up [this](http://www.birch.com.tw/newpage/template/RPu420ProgramManual.pdf) application programming guide.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

[JSR-82 Bluetooth API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_APIs_for_Bluetooth) support L2CAP protocol, RFCOMM and OBEX profile. I don't know detail of Bluetooth basic printing profile (BPP) but, if you look into [basic printing profile](http://www.bluetooth.com/NR/rdonlyres/28EC09DC-1598-4889-9B7E-3E8D9803FFBA/2940/BPP_SPEC_V12r01.pdf) document you can find that BPP built on OBEX profile.

I can't find open source project for BPP on JSR-82. Please try to search it, but if you can't find one you might need to write your own.

Comment: thanks for the reply. however,the epson tm-p60 only supports SPP (serial port profile) so i can't use BPP

Comment: The printer he is using does not speak BPP, it speaks ESC/POS.